Charging 1.2V batteries with a solar cell
I have a pendulum driven by an electromagnet that I've been powering by two 1.2 volt 2000 ma Ni-mH rechargeable batteries in parallel. I've gotten the pendulum to swing for 3 months on this setup. I want to add a solar cell to recharge the batteries during the day to keep this swinging indefinitely and not have to replace or recharge the batteries. I have some 1.5 v 160 ma solar cells I was hoping to add to the circuit. Am I safe adding the diode between the solar cell and battery and connecting it to the circuit or do I need to add something else?
Thanks,
Wylie

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Check the voltage you actually get out of the solar cells in good light.  A diode can drop between 0.2 to 0.6V, depending on which type you get.  That may leave the voltage too low to charge the batteries.  You really want a charging voltage around 1.4V.
Don't over-charge the cells.  If you intend to do anything more than a trickle charge, then you need a proper NiMH charger.  One 160 mA panel is quite a low current for 4000 mAh of cells, and you could get away with that.  Multiple solar cells in parallel could be too much.

Thanks for your reply. In full sun at noon in MN the solar cell produced 1.8 volts and 160 ma. I am somewhat confident the circuit draws around 100 ma of current per day. From what I have read, if the solar cell is connected in series (with a diode) and the rechargeable battery, the circuit will draw from the power source that is supplying more voltage. So during the day the circuit will draw from the solar cell and what the circuit does not use will go into recharging the battery.

Is that correct? Will this help extend the life of the pendulum swing and it is safe? I am open to switching to different mah batteries if I need to as well.

The voltage of the solar panel will naturally drop to the voltage of the load.  So that isn't a problem.  If the batteries normally last 3 months, then you only need a trickle charge anyway.
